# TYPO3 query equals by another table

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18, and I have problem with query.

this works

```
public function getFiltered($offset = 0, $limit = 5){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->equals('cruserId', 3));
    return $query->execute();
```

But this not works

```
public function getFiltered($offset = 0, $limit = 5){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->equals('cruserId.uid', 3));

    return $query->execute();
```

this return empty. Why? I filter by condition in another table(fe_users). I  need filter by uid, gender or other fields. I don't know where is a problem.

TCA:

```
'cruser_id' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:fefiles/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo.cruser_id',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'appearance' => [
            'collapseAll' => 0,
            'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
            'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
            'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
            'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
        ],
    ]
],
```

Model:

```
  /**
     * CruserId
     *
     * @var \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User
     * @inject
     */
    protected $cruserId;

    /**
     * Returns the cruserId
     *
     * @return \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\User $cruserId
     */
    public function getCruserId()
    {
        return $this->cruserId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the cruserId
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCruserId($cruserId)
    {
        $this->cruserId = $cruserId;
    }
```

If I use cruserId.uid - it just return empty. I had specially create test ext by extension builder and make my model, tca the same, but it return empty. Help me please, good people) Do you now where is problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 individual query filter by another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941882/typo3-individual-query-filter-by-another-table)

Comment: yes, I just thought that my problem is solved because it does't return error. But it return empty

Answer (score 1):

I think `cruserId.uid` is not your Tables fields. in TYPO3 Extabase query syntax you need to pass always feilds name like.

> $query->equals($propertyName, $operand, $caseSensitive = true )

**Parameters**

- **string**   $propertyName   The name of the property to compare against
- **mixed**    $operand    The value to compare with
- **bool** $caseSensitive  Whether the equality test should be done
  case-sensitive

For more infromation [TYPO3 Query syntax](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/8/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_generic_1_1_query.html#a7b23660bbacad6ff89b0cc75a585c43b)

Comment: $query->matching($query->equals('image.uid', 3)); - that's works.
$query->matching($query->equals('user.uid', 3)); - it must works too

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
        $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(false);
```

this solved my problem

Comment: In that case you most likely haven't set a `storagePid` in your TypoScript/plugin settings.